# PowerBI Report Server security issue: How to avoid direct access to Report Server URL through the web browser?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

We have a serious security issue regarding Power BI Report Server.

We depolyed a power bi report server report URL on a web portal but the URL is easy to catch after inspection on the portal and a user can have access to data of all other customers.

So we would like to avoid direct access to the URL through the web browser and avoid random people over the internet to access the ReportServer.

- I would like to specify that we are using SSO (SAML) authentication mode on Power BI Report Server and with this mode we can not use RLS. What we are doing to manage users access to filtered data is adding filters in the Report Server URL. The problem is that those filters are not hidden and could be modified or deleted from users after catching the Report Server URL from the browser console (Network).
- Domains of the report server and the web portal are different.
- Data loading mode: Import.

Has anyone come across this requirement before? Any thoughts or suggested solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you presenting the ReportViewer to your users, or rendering a document, like a PDF, etc?  Can you clarify how you are using "SSO (SAML)" on Report Server?  Is it through Azure Application Proxy, as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/azure-application-proxy ?

Comment: Reports are displayed via an Iframe integrated into a web page using the following library: https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-angular. SAML authentication is used in a JAVA JEE application, the token retrieved from azure is used to
connect to the power bi instance in the azure AD.

Comment: That's for embedding with the Power BI Service, not Power BI Report Server.